# BSOD: Error code:0x0000007B

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-registry, operating-systems, bsod

Recently I received a "`Blue Screen of Death".The error message I recieved was "A problem was detected and windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer.Error code:0x0000007B`"

Steps taken to resolve this problem

1.Safe mode -- **Does not seem to work,same result**

2.Last known configuration -- **Does not seem to work,same result**

3.Windows Startup Repair -- **Error message**

```
   Boot Configuration is corrupt

   Repair action: Partition table repair
   Result:Failed Error Code = 0x490
   Time Taken:2637ms
```

4.Tried reinstalling windows

```
  Found the C drive where windows was installed, is not showing up in the list of drives.Shows D and E drive
```

5.Booted from Live OS(Ubuntu 14)

```
  Shows all the drives C,D and E.I had all my data backed up to my external harddisk.
```

Could someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Error code `7b` refers to your hard drive and/or controller.  Boot from Windows 7 DVD. Choose *"Repair my PC"* and get the command prompt:

```
chkdsk /R c:

chkdsk /R d:

chkdsk /r E:
```

Then reboot.

If it works, After that you seriously want to consider getting a new hdd and cloning the data over and replacing the drive.

Answer (score 0):

The hard drive could be packed up resulting in loss of data at the later stage if only repaired...

My advice would be to remove that HDD, plug it on a different machine as a slave to perform your backups, then format the entire hard to confirm its consistency, reinstall the OS, then restore your data.

If all that fails, replace hard drive